# Are android system kernel panic logs available in TWRP recovery?

Tags: custom-roms, kernel, logging

I am trying to debug a rom I built but can't seem to find the any kernel panic or system logs in TWRP recovery.

Is it possible to create logs for a failed boot to see whats going wrong?

I am still a total noob with this stuff so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check /sys/fs/pstore immediately after a crash

In some cases there are no logs here as the device warm resets (it happens when a crash is serious enough to boot the device into edl). To avoid this try disabling kernel panics in your kernel.